# Content is overlapping while using stack in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/painting.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
  home: Home(),
));`class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(

      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('GigoClean',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'Roboto',
          ),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.cyanAccent[400],
      ),`body:  Center(
        child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
           Container(
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              image: new DecorationImage(image: new AssetImage("assets/bg.png"), fit: BoxFit.cover,),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 90.0, 0, 0),
            child: Image.asset('assets/intro.jpg'),
          ),
          Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 40, 15, 0),
              child: Text('Get ready to make your life easy with single click of app, which makes your cleaning easy.' ,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
```

> I only want a background image, that's why i am using stack but it is overlapping other content as well. Please help!!

Comment: Please share a screenshot by highlighting your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put the other two Containers inside a Column or a Row to avoid overlapping. Here is an example for your understanding:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(

  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('GigoClean',
      style: TextStyle(
        fontFamily: 'Roboto',
      ),
    ),
    centerTitle: true,
    backgroundColor: Colors.cyanAccent[400],
  ),`body:  Center(
    child: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
       Container(
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
          image: new DecorationImage(image: new AssetImage("assets/bg.png"), fit: BoxFit.cover,),
        ),
      ),
      Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 90.0, 0, 0),
            child: Image.asset('assets/intro.jpg'),
          ),
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 40, 15, 0),
            child: Text('Get ready to make your life easy with single click of app, which makes your cleaning easy.' ,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
```